# android: show an alert dialog from the action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, alert, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to showing an AlertDialog when an item of an action bar is clicked, but nothing happens!!! I'm new to android programming so could you post me some code or tell me how to do this?

thanks to everyone!!

Matteo

Comment: Can you post your existing code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, firstly you have to catch the event onclick when the item of the action bar is clicked right?

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home)   //the androi.r.id.home have to changed
                                                 //for the id of your button.
    {
       ///here is where you have to show the alertdialog!!!!
    } 
}




public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
        //This is the layout that you are going to use in your alertdialog
        final View addView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add, null);

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Add a Word").setView(addView)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        addWord((TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.title));
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).show();

         return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
```

get full source form here..

http://vimaltuts.com/android-tutorial-for-beginners/android-action-bar-tab-menu-example

Also you can build your AlertDialgog like that:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
   .setTitle("Delete entry")
   .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")
   .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        // continue with delete
      }
    })
   .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        // do nothing
      }
    })
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
 .show();
```

Comment: Can you mark as a solution is it is working for you? Thanks!!! Don't hesitate to ask whatever that you need.

Comment: I've just implemented it and it worked! I did the same yesterday but I don't know why this didn't worked!

Comment: Ok, good to heard...anyway, if my solution is good, maybe you can/should/must check as the right solution, right?

Answer (score 2):

Show your code. Example would be something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.itemid:
           new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
           .setMessage("Message")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               //code if yes
           }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("No", null)
           .show();

       return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```